# How to get overflow:scroll to display at the bottom of the scroll window

Tags: html, css

I have a series of messages that I want to display in a window of fixed size and have it overflow: scroll. The issue is that I do not want the older messages to show up first and have the users scroll to the bottom just to see the most recent messages. It there a way I can get the scroll window to display at the bottom of it?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a pure html/css solution as well but for that you can use JavaScript, first get the scroll height of that message box and then scroll to its bottom. This may help: https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window

Comment: If you write this as an answer I'll check it off.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to sort with newest messages on top?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrollHeight is the height of the content in an element *assuming* there was no scrollbars on that element. In case of the example below, it's the height of the 10 message paragraphs together. Also by setting the scrollTop, we have moved the scrollbar down. This is what you asked for:

```js
        let msgbox = document.querySelector('.msgbox');
        msgbox.scrollTop = msgbox.scrollHeight; // <-- This does the trick
```

```css
.msgbox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
    <div class="msgbox">
        <p>message 1</p>
        <p>message 2</p>
        <p>message 3</p>
        <p>message 4</p>
        <p>message 5</p>
        <p>message 6</p>
        <p>message 7</p>
        <p>message 8</p>
        <p>message 9</p>
        <p>message 10</p>
    </div>
```